# Start showing images on TTPhotoViewController using the index of the photosource

Tags: iphone, three20

I have set a TTPhotoViewController to display a XML retrieved photosource.
It is working, but I want to be able to start the controller showing another given photo from my datasource that is not the first one (start showing the third, or the fourth for example)
Anyone knows how to do this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I believe the centerPhoto property is what you should be setting

Answer (score 1):

_centerPhotoIndex property.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    ...
    _centerPhotoIndex = 2;
}
```